# Is [Enthusiast] badge working correctly

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

Everyday working hard to earn that badge, and then at day 26 out of 30, it resets starting all over now. Now I am in such a depression I couldn't initially visit the site anymore (what a geek I am).

However in that case, I am somehow sure I did visit the site every day. I did it first thing in the morning, and later in the day again (at least in the evening). So that should have covered for 'UTC' measurements. I can only see that for one day I do not have history commenting/flagging/asking/reviewing/answering.

My suspicion is somehow that the badge does not completely or exactly work as advertised, or maybe it does not register 'site visits' on a mobile device? Maybe I am just wrong?

Comment: Yes, the badge is working correctly. No, just visiting the front page is *not enough*. You need to be active on the site every day (where days start at UTC midnight).

Comment: Just to make sure, days are counted as 24-hour periods per based on UTC midnight?  Not as time last seen?

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's right. According to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731): "Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are not counted in local time"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro that section of the post pretty much answers this question.  Want to do us the honor of posting the answer here on SO?

Comment: Ah oops. Misread the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What constitutes "active" on the site?

Comment: @Aify that's not made public to prevent gaming.

Comment: Considering I got the [Fanatic] tag yesterday, I can only assume that [Enthusiast] is working.

Comment: I would argue you're not "working hard" for it if all you did was visit the front page a bunch of times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and all, thanks for the responses. Little bit of a badge hangover to deal with. Note that badge description states that visit is enough ... Didn't mention need for other activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [List of all Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188731) page states:

> **Participation Badges**
>
> **Enthusiast**
>
> - silver
> - awarded once Visit the site for 30 days in a row
>
> **Fanatic**
>
> - gold
> - awarded once Visit the site for 100 days in a row
>
> [**Note:**] Additional criteria for this badge family:
>
> - **Simply loading the site is not enough to count as a "visit"**. The exact amount of activity required to count as a visit is not public information.
> - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are not counted in local time.

It is clearly indicated that merely logging in is not enough to count as participation. What is not clear is whether you have to remain logged in for 24 hrs at a time for it to count.

My understanding regarding the timing criteria is that you cannot log in multiple times the same day and think you are going to count more than once. The system time stamps your logging in and out and then compares the time stamps with UTC time as the measuring stick.

Another discussion on this topic can be found at: [Consecutive days problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments:  days are counted as 24-hour periods per based on UTC midnight.

This caught me out too, when I was badge hunting.  I hate it.  I still do (for example, this applies to the voting limit too, so because I did a bunch of voting last night, now I can't vote for a while today, in my timezone).