# Enthusiast badge problem

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, consecutive-days

The Enthusiast badge (and other badges that require the user to visit the site every day more than 7 days in a row) prevent religious Jewish people from earning it even though they are very enthusiastic.

That is because they keep the Sabbath (the seventh day) and **don't use any electric device including a computer** (excluding devices that work by themselves without human interaction).

So starting from Friday (before sunset), until Saturday (after 3 stars appear in the sky), they can't be in SO. A quick calculation shows that it's always more than 24 hours, and every 7 days (not to mention holidays that defined as sabbath - not all are like this).

I believe this should change the badge earning criteria. The preferred way (in my opinion) is to require 25 days out of 30 to get the badge, instead of 30/30 as now.

Comment: That would require a religion-specific software change.  Your temple volunteering to pay for it?

Comment: I don't think any of us are defined as enthusiasts of Stack Overflow just because we have a badge for it. I only use it on weekdays and to say I'm less enthusiastic than a robot that does a daily login is laughable,

Comment: Would it be in violation of the Sabbath to write a userscript which made a visit for you?

Comment: No, but it makes a feel like the badge is the target, instead of a reward for activity. and it makes me feel like I'm waisting my time on nonsense, instead of being helpful to the community and to myself

Comment: @Yitzchak I thought many times about it but never actually brought it up. Thank you. I am sorry that it wasn't well perceived.

Comment: @TravisJ, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334880/402789) and to some comments on that question, simply visiting the front page is not enough to count as a visit. So, writing a userscript to make a visit won't work.

Comment: @Alexandre - Amusing, but terribly misled. I am not sure what you think "that answer" actually mentions with regards to visiting the front page as it references simply logging in. Userscripts can accomplish this without any issue at all. The visitation counting is done during authenticated requests, which is easy as pie to do. Even if it were complicated, you could simply make a series of onload browser extensions to follow a path of page requests and interactions. Please, do some research before you make any statements of absolution.

Comment: @TravisJ What I understood from the comments is that there is a somewhat complex validation of the user interaction with the site, in order to consider he/she really made a visit, that is, the user must really interact with the site and not only access a few pages. Making a script to resemble that actions is surely possible (after all, knowing how to script enables you to make almost anything), but if the validation is complex enough, then the script should be as complex as it or even more, if the validation was made to also avoid automation. […]

Comment: @TravisJ […] Since there is no info about what is considered a valid visit, in order to prevent gaming (as said in the comments), it would probably be very hard to achieve a working script, and even if possible, it should be discouraged, as it diminishes the purpose of the badge (reward the user for being active in the site). I understand that you was offering an option to solve the OP's problem, and I agree with you that it could be achieved with a script, but I also consider the badge is not that important and also not that meaningful to indicate that the user is really active.

Comment: @Alexandre - No info? If only someone who was familiar with the framework, and overall design of the site, had written about counting views... hmm? [Oh, right... I did that.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224165/178816)

Comment: @TravisJ - When I said "no info", I was relying on what the users said in the comments on the answer/question I linked above (especially this one: `@Aify that's not made public to prevent gaming. – Martijn Pieters`). Since I'm only a beginner user and Martijn Pieters is a moderator with 980k rep, I presumed that he was right and that such information was kept safe. Also I don't see the direct relation between counting views on users' profiles or on questions and counting a particular user's interaction as a valid visit. […]

Comment: @TravisJ […] If cache won't persist for more than 15 minutes, just opening the front page once a day should count as a visit, but based on those comments, it seems that it is not enough… ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just letting you know. I already have the badge, the accepted answer helped me :)  it was my first golden badge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The visitor badges badges use the UTC "day". That is they count midnight UTC (00:00:00) as the start of the day and 23:59:59 as the end. The visits don't have to be 24 hours apart, just in 30 or 365 consecutive 24 hour periods. You could have two visits less than 5 minutes apart that span UTC midnight and get two consecutive days there and then. If you had your first visit at just after UTC midnight you could then wait nearly 48 hours before your next visit and still get a consecutive day.

So depending on your timezone you can visit on the Friday before your local sunset and again on the Saturday after the stars appear in the sky and still have the visits count as consecutive days.

Assume that you are 2 hours ahead of UTC. Your visit on the Friday will be around 18:00 local/16:00 UTC (in the autumn). Your visit on the Saturday will be after 18:00 local/16:00 UTC (assuming that the stars are only visible after sunset) but as long as the Saturday visit is before 02:00 local time, the visits are on consecutive days.

I agree it's tricky, but it is possible.

Comment: It would help if you have a fast private jet.

Comment: thx. I believe it's a reasonable solution

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334880/402789) and to some comments on that question, simply visiting the front page is not enough to count as a visit. So, it may be a little trickier than that.